# Android Fragment Replace but Fragment won't Disappear

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-fragments

I cannot get my old `fragment` to disappear when I try to switch fragments. I am trying to switch between fragments using this code

```
  getActivity().getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.blank_fragment, nextFrag)
                        .addToBackStack(null)
                        .commit();
```

The new fragment loads, but the old fragment doesn't completely disappear.

Everything disappears except the **top tableRow**, dayRow. Here is what my `xml` looks like

```
<TableRow
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/dayRow">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Sun"
        android:id="@+id/sunText"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Mon"
        android:id="@+id/monText"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Tue"
        android:id="@+id/tueText"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Wed"
        android:id="@+id/wedText"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Thu"
        android:id="@+id/thuText"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Fri"
        android:id="@+id/friText"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Sat"
        android:id="@+id/satText"
        android:gravity="center" />

</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:id="@+id/rowOne"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/rowOneDate1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:onClick="test"
        android:clickable="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/rowOneDate2"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/rowOneDate3"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/rowOneDate4"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/rowOneDate5"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/rowOneDate6"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/rowOneDate7"
        android:gravity="center" />

</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:id="@+id/rowTwo"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/rowTwoDate1"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/rowTwoDate2"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/rowTwoDate3"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/rowTwoDate4"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/rowTwoDate5"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/rowTwoDate6"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/rowTwoDate7"
        android:gravity="center" />

</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:id="@+id/rowThree"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/rowThreeDate1"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/rowThreeDate2"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/rowThreeDate3"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/rowThreeDate4"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/rowThreeDate5"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/rowThreeDate6"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/rowThreeDate7"
        android:gravity="center" />

</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:id="@+id/rowFour"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/rowFourDate1"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/rowFourDate2"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/rowFourDate3"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/rowFourDate4"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/rowFourDate5"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/rowFourDate6"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/rowFourDate7"
        android:gravity="center" />

</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:id="@+id/rowFive"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/rowFiveDate1"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/rowFiveDate2"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/rowFiveDate3"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/rowFiveDate4"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/rowFiveDate5"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/rowFiveDate6"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/rowFiveDate7"
        android:gravity="center" />

</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:id="@+id/rowSix"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/rowSixDate1"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/rowSixDate2"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/rowSixDate3"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/rowSixDate4"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/rowSixDate5"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/rowSixDate6"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/rowSixDate7"
        android:gravity="center" />

</TableRow>
```

The top row in my table `layout` stays even after I change `layouts`.

If I change the `layout weight` for first table row (dayRow) to 1 it disappears like I want it to,

but I want the `layout` `height` to still `wrap content`.

so any help and Suggestion  is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Simply set root layout background to

```
android:background="?android:attr/colorBackground"
```

Comment: How come the other rows disappear but the top one doesn't?

Comment: @user3558585: Bcoz it got weekdays entry, try to enter some values in other rows. To completely disappear the fragment u need to set the root element's background to android:background="?android:attr/colorBackground"